# Estimating Appropriate Risk Premiums without Comparable Project Data

Tags: risk, returns

### Objective

I wish to estimate an approximate reasonable return (a) for a project, given its inherent risk and risk-free rate, and compare that to the anticipated project return (b).

Such that, all else being equal, a <= b or b >= a means the investment is appropriately compensated for the risk. Or, in plain terms, if I expect the project to yield returns that are greater than the estimated returns for a project of similar risk, then the return is appropriate given the risk.

However, no data is available for comparable projects of similar risk levels.

Based on a Monte Carlo simulation of the project (n = 1000 simulations), I have the following assumptions:

```
[return] <- 0.1472577 # mean simulated return for the project
[sd] <- 0.1157628 # The standard deviation for the simulated project returns
[risk-free return] <- 0.02 # given assumption
```

### Questions

1. Can this information be used to estimate a reasonable risk-adjusted return for comparison to the anticipated return? If so, how?
2. If not, is there a commonly accepted method for estimating appropriate returns where comparable projects do not exist for comparison.

### Additional Discussion

Originally I was thinking of something like...

```
[appropriate return] <- [risk-free return] + [some premium or discount based on risk-free rate and inherent risk]
```

...using the Monte Carlo data to represent comparable projects.

I was experimenting with using Sharpes Ratio (SR) to calculate a risk-adjusted return.

```
[sr] <- ([simulated mean return] - [risk-free return]) / [standard deviation of simulated returns]

[risk adjusted return] <- [risk-free return] + [sr] * ([simulated mean return] - [risk-free return])
```

I have a problem with this approach in that SR appears to be the reverse of what is needed here.  Presumably, as risk increases, so does the risk premium. The risk premium uses SR as a factor, so greater SR means a greater premium. If Standard deviation is our representation of risk, then greater sd = greater risk.  But as a denominator in the SR formula (all else being equal), greater risk = lower SR = lower premium. So this appears to be the wrong tool.

I also wondered if the simulated mean already approximates the reasonable return of a comparable project.  The mean represents the centre point of possible outcomes. However, it doesn't consider the risk-free rate.

Thanks